# How Add Anchor Tags by repeater and To Jump To Specific Location On A Page?

Tags: c#, html, anchor

I want to use repeater to populate anchors and links to that anchors dynamically.
I know for statistic case we can do this:

```
<a href="#anchor">Link Text</a>
```

and the anchor :

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

Now, to create the link dynamically I use:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="LinkRepeater" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  class="TopMenuBarLink" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link")%>'>
      <%# Eval("Title")%>
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But when I run the program, on the website, use inspect element I get this for the links:

```
<a id="_ctl0_viewCompanies_LinkRepeater_HyperLink1_0" class="TopMenuBarLink" href="Mypath/MyAnchor">My title text</a>
```

How do I get it in the right form:

```
 <a id="_ctl0_viewCompanies_LinkRepeater_HyperLink1_0" class="TopMenuBarLink" href="#MyAnchor">My title text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific reason that you're using a server control for your hyperlink? why not use a normal anchor element.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="LinkRepeater" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <a class="TopMenuBarLink" href='#<%# Eval("Link")%>'>
      <%# Eval("Title")%>
    </a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Yes, you find the right point ! Actually I want to use normal anchor element but I cannot write it in correct format. And thanks for your suggestion, it works perfectly! Kudo to you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this (add the # symbol before the ASP.Net code bracket):

```
NavigateUrl='#<%# Eval("Link")%>'
```

Comment: No, it will still give some prefix before the MyAnchor, and it shows strange character: <a id="_ctl0_viewCompanies_LinkRepeater_HyperLink1_0" class="TopMenuBarLink" href="MyPath/#%3C%25%23%20Eval(%22Link%22)%25%3E">casting</a>